# CSS Responsive with odd layout

Tags: html, css

I have a client asking for a very odd request (to me).

Ok, so I have 3 images. All different sizes. They want them in a wrapped container, equal heights. Images positioned at the bottom, text at bottom.

Now, doing this is easy... until you get to the responsive part.

This site:
http://www.neilcramerphotography.com/

Full screen, they look ok (still working with it). But once you resize the screen (which I foresaw happening) the layout gets all wonky.

I only need to worry about the first 6 images, rest is set design.

No matter what I do or use, there is some sort of fixed number. Like I have to set a fixed height for each of the first two rows. Tried padding. Getting frustrated because I can usually solve most problems. Just stuck.And if it is NOT doable. I need others stating so. People never believe me,so :)

**I may have to try percentages instead.**

I wish people understood not everything you do on paper can not always be easily converted to something like this without problems. A layout from some other designer that does not know CSS.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please see [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

add `box-sizing: border-box` to your `.woo_category_subs`

Is this what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Are they open to a 3rd party library?  I'd personally recommend [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/).  It's a very powerful, scaleable framework. In addition to carousels, navbars, glyphicons, accordians, and bunch of other doodads, it supports responsive image resizing through a breakpoint based grid system.  I use it on my personal [website and blog](http://jamesjmtaylor.com)  which you can test the responsiveness of with Google Chrome's inspector (accessible inside any Browser with CTRL + SHIFT + I).  An example of a responsive image from my website is below:

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4"> 
  <a class="linkPic" href="mailto:james.jm.taylor@gmail.comSubject=Nice%20website!" 
     title="My Email" target="_top" rel="external">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="images/mail.jpg" alt="Email me">
  </a>
</div>
```

The magic happens in the class declaration for the first div tag.  Specifically "col-lg-2 col-sm-3 col-xs-4".  What this translates to is an application of a bootstrap css size rule scaling the picture to 1/6 screen size on desktops, 1/4 on tablets, and 1/3 on smartphones (the bootstrap grid is 12 columns wide, and lg, sm, and xs corespond to desktop, tablet, and smartphone respectively).

Hope this helps.